# can cos() function have more variety in terms of animation movement?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, keyframes, drivers

I always use cos() driver expression to make simple loop animation.
1st animation curve is baked result of cos(frame/5) of driver expression.

[image]

And I think it's too predictable and it needs to be 2nd curve, which has randomness on X axis(timing)and Y axis(key frame value).  Is it possible to make 2nd animation curve using cos() function? Y axis randomness is what I need right now but X axis randomness can be useful too. I would like to control both randomness separately.

Comment: Do you want to use these waves to animate object positions? Geometry nodes can do this, and so can scripts.

Comment: I use it to move bones. It makes character's simple movement like idle animation and breathing.  Is it possible to let cos() have more variety?

Comment: Yes, it's available in the driver, I'll provide info later.

Comment: tbh this is not a Blender question, but a mathematical question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

##### Goal 1: Move the min/max point up/down of a cos function

[image]

Assume you want to move first minimum point -1 on t = pi, then the function of t in (0, pi) be $1.5*cos x-0.5$

[image]

Simair, the second function: $2.2*cos x+0.2$

[image]

```
t = frame   function                y
0 ~ pi      1.5 * cos(x) - 0.5      1 ~ -2
pi ~ 2pi    2.2 * cos(x) + 0.2      -2 ~ 2.4
2pi ~ 3pi   1.8 * cos(x) + 0.6      2.4 ~ -1.2
3pi ~ 4pi   1.1 * cos(x) - 0.1      -1.2 ~ 1
... loop
```

thus,

```
expression = 1.5 * cos(frame) - 0.5  if frame % (2*tau) < pi else (2.2 * cos(frame) + 0.2  if frame % (2*tau) < tau else (1.8 * cos(frame) + 0.6   if frame % (2*tau) < tau + pi else 1.1 * cos(frame) - 0.1))
```

Result:

[image]

With speed Factor:

```
# 1/20 speed
# speedFac = 0.05

expression = 1.5 * cos((frame*speedFac)) - 0.5  if (frame*speedFac) % (2*tau) < pi else (2.2 * cos((frame*speedFac)) + 0.2  if (frame*speedFac) % (2*tau) < tau else (1.8 * cos((frame*speedFac)) + 0.6   if (frame*speedFac) % (2*tau) < tau + pi else 1.1 * cos((frame*speedFac)) - 0.1))
```

##### Goal 2: Move the min/max point left/right of a cos function

[image]

Simair method,

```
t = frame           function                        y
0 ~ 2pi/3           cos(1.5 * x)                    1 ~ -1
2pi/3 ~ 44pi/21     cos(0.7 * (x + 16 * pi / 21))   -1 ~ 1
44pi/21 ~ 281pi/84  cos(0.8 * (x + 17 * pi / 42))   1 ~ -1
281pi/84 ~ 117pi/28 cos(1.2 * (x + 23 * pi / 28))  -1 ~ 1
... loop

expression = cos(1.5 * frame%(117*pi/28))  if frame%(117*pi/28) < 2*pi/3 else (cos(0.7 * (frame%(117*pi/28) + 16 * pi / 21))  if frame%(117*pi/28) < 44*pi/21  else (cos(0.8 * (frame%(117*pi/28) + 17 * pi / 42))  if frame%(117*pi/28) < 281*pi/84 else cos(1.2 * (frame%(117*pi/28) + 23 * pi / 28))))
```

[image]

With speed factor:

```
expression = cos(1.5 * (frame*speedFac)%(117*pi/28))  if (frame*speedFac)%(117*pi/28) < 2*pi/3 else (cos(0.7 * ((frame*speedFac)%(117*pi/28) + 16 * pi / 21))  if (frame*speedFac)%(117*pi/28) < 44*pi/21  else (cos(0.8 * ((frame*speedFac)%(117*pi/28) + 17 * pi / 42))  if (frame*speedFac)%(117*pi/28) < 281*pi/84 else cos(1.2 * ((frame*speedFac)%(117*pi/28) + 23 * pi / 28))))
```

In theory, as the function gets more complex, it becomes more random

##### Other method

$\cos\left(x\right)+2\cos\left(2x+2\right)-3\cos\left(3x\right)$

[image]

Comment: On the other hand, animating with keyframes is also a good option, it has some function like noise modifier.

Comment: thank you I am gonna break down your expression so it will take some time. one more question I always use  custom properties to change animation speed and its intensity like
animation_speed = 0.5
animation_Intensity = 0.1
cos(frame/animation_speed)*(animation_intensity)
I need to use those variables, but how can I combine yours with those variables?

Comment: Replace `frame` with `(frame*speedFac)`. View the answer.

Comment: Intensity: multiply `k` by the function, `k*f(x) if a > b else k*g(x)`

Comment: It seems working fine now but I may ask you something later. thank you.